# nodejs api that returns the region and zone where the pod is running in a GCP K8S cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have nodejs code running inside a pod. From inside the pod I want to find the zone of the node where this pod is running. What is the best way do do that? Do I need extra permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to find a library but I post the code that does it below. The getContent function was slightly adapted from this [post](https://www.tomas-dvorak.cz/posts/nodejs-request-without-dependencies/) This code should work inside a GKE pod or and GCE host.

Use it as following:

```
const gcp = require('./gcp.js')
gcp.zone().then(z  => console.log('Zone is: ' + z))
```

Module: gcp.js

```
const getContent = function(lib, options) {
  // return new pending promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // select http or https module, depending on reqested url
    const request = lib.get(options, (response) => {
      // handle http errors
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
         reject(new Error('Failed to load page, status code: ' + response.statusCode));
       }
      // temporary data holder
      const body = [];
      // on every content chunk, push it to the data array
      response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
      // we are done, resolve promise with those joined chunks
      response.on('end', () => resolve(body.join('')));
    });
    // handle connection errors of the request
    request.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
    })
};

exports.zone = () => {
    return getContent(
        require('http'),
        {
            hostname: 'metadata.google.internal',
            path: '/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone',
            headers: {
                'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
            },
            method: 'GET'
        }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region` and `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone` labels of the pod to getting its region and AZ.

But, please keep in mind, that:

> Only GCE and AWS are currently supported automatically (though it is easy to add similar support for other clouds or even bare metal, by simply arranging for the appropriate labels to be added to nodes and volumes).

To get access to labels, you can use `DownwardAPI` for attaching a `Volume` with your current labels and annotations of the pod. You don't need any extra permissions for use it, just mount them as a volume.

Here is an example from a [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/):

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-downwardapi-volume-example
  labels:
    zone: us-est-coast
    cluster: test-cluster1
    rack: rack-22
  annotations:
    build: two
    builder: john-doe
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          if [[ -e /etc/podinfo/labels ]]; then
            echo -en '\n\n'; cat /etc/podinfo/labels; fi;
          if [[ -e /etc/podinfo/annotations ]]; then
            echo -en '\n\n'; cat /etc/podinfo/annotations; fi;
          sleep 5;
        done;
      volumeMounts:
        - name: podinfo
          mountPath: /etc/podinfo
          readOnly: false
  volumes:
    - name: podinfo
      downwardAPI:
        items:
          - path: "labels"
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.labels
          - path: "annotations"
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations`

When you have a mounted volume with labels, you can read a file `/etc/labels` which will contain information about AZ and Region as a Key-Pairs, like this:
`failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1c`

Comment: @AntonI also thought that the downward API can help on this but this is not an answer to the question, it is just a lead to be pursued. I have tried a number of different ways but still cannot get to that information.

Comment: @gaie123 actually using Labels is the best way to do that. I updated an answer and add some details about how to mounted labels.

Comment: It looks like only Pod Label is propagated in this way, node label is not in there.